# Getting a senior job without the yrs of experience asked for

Tags: c#

My manager in my current company feels that I am selling myself short by getting another job - but as a senior. He feels I have sold myself short and missing out on a good salary by getting another junior job, given how he (my manager) has a lot of faith in my development skills.

However, I have not worked long enough for a proper senior job (5 years +) but then the senior developer we do have in my current company isn't given senior tasks (judged by difficulty).

How would I get a senior job if I lack the commercial experience? My manager still feels without that, I have the ability/knowledge (I help my manager with C# too).

Thanks

Comment: When I hire devs, years of experience is only a rough guide.  If I see a top resume, I'll speak with the candidate if they're anywhere in the ballpark experience-wise.  I even recently hired someone right out of college for a mid-level position because he impressed me on paper and in the interviews.  Turned out to be a great decision.

Comment: don't take this the wrong way, but I am going to be honest and say that, at this point in time, judging from your q/a, you would probably be setting yourself up for failure if, by some odd circumstance, you were hired as a senior developer. Get some years under your belt in a situation where you can grow organically as opposed to being under the gun. Good luck.

Comment: based on your question "Difference between i++ and ++i in a loop?"  I would agree with the code poet.  Nothing wrong with taking your time and working at the right job.  Crashing and burning in a position that's over your head can be hard on your career.  Doesn't hurt to be patient and it sounds like you have a manager that's willing to work with you.  That is very valuable....

Comment: I've re-read the question at least 4x's now and am still confused, re: if your manager has great faith in your development skills, why isn't your manager giving you senior-level responsibilities? Or is it just the title you are seeking?

Answer (score 0):

Network and see if a friend/colleague who knows your up to the challenge can help you get into something more at your level.  If you're dealing with a stranger who is just trying to put checks in a box I don't think you'll have much luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think its all about selling yourself. Also in some companies they promote their developers to "senior software engineer" after one year, such as Accenture. A title doesn't necessarily have a required amount of years of experience attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try for a Sr. programmer job and take a good referral letter from your current manager to help make your case.

However, if you just can't make the argument, take a Jr. programmer job somewhere else and PROVE to them that you deserve to be a Sr. Programmer. If your current manager is correct, then you should have no trouble doing that.

Comment: This is exactly my strategy. I just got a job with a big software company, so I expect the whole performance review stuff and therefore I expect to do well enough to get pay rise/promotion.

Answer (score 0):

Another line is to see if you can find companies looking for intermediate/senior developers as this would be a way to get your foot in the door.  Lastly, don't forget that what one companies calls senior may not be the same somewhere else so one could have little experience yet still get a senior title as the company believes that may make one happier than other stuff.